# Python - checking for characters in date string

Tags: python, date

I'm just kind of confused with Python at the moment.
I want to ask the user to input the date in a specific format. But I also want to check if there are two "/" in the input. Ex: MM/DD/YYYY.... or else I would output an error message.

This is what I have so far:

```
date = str((raw_input("Please enter a date in the form MM/DD/YYYY: ")))
while date[(2),(5)]!="/":
    date_input=(str(raw_input("Error: Your date must be in the format YYYY/MM/DD including the slashes, try again: ")))
```

But I'm pretty stuck. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: First you ask for a date in a certain format and put it in a certain variable, but then, if it has the wrong format, you then ask for it in a _different_ format and put it in a _different_ variable! By the way, `raw_import` returns a string, so there's no need to use `str`.

Comment: Also, date[(2),(5)] is invented syntax...

Answer (score 2):

Use `datetime.strptime` to parse the date, and it will tell you when the format is wrong:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.now()
try:
    d.strptime(date_str, "%d/%m/%Y")
except ValueError:
    print "Bad format!"
```